# How to find position of similar elements in array using java

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose i have an array:

```
input[] = {1,2,3,2,2,3,1,3,2}
```

I want to find all the positions of each distinct element within this array and store them in new arrays. The output should be as below:

```
output_1[] = {0,6} //Position of "1" in input array
output_2[] = {1,3,4,8} //Position of "2" in input array
output_3[] = {2,5,7} //Position of "3" in input array
```

The code should be applicable for an array with any size and any number of distinct elements.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Averroes i have identified the unique elements as for now..like 1,2,3 for any given array in java..but i'm not sure how to find the positions of all unique elements in general case where the number of unique elements keeps changing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will fill a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` with the positions of any distinct value found in the input Array. Since the `Map` cannot contain duplicate keys, it is useful for storing all positions of similar elements. You can see I check if the `Map` already contains a Key for a given value, and if it does I add its position to the existing `List`. If not, I create a new `List` with the value's position as initial value.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sandbox {
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> positions;
    private int[] input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Sandbox()).run();
    }

    public Sandbox() {
        positions = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
        input = new int[] { 1,2,3,2,2,3,1,3,2 };
    }

    private void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            Integer value = input[i];

            if(positions.containsKey(value)) {
                List<Integer> list = positions.get(value);
                list.add(i);
            } else {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                list.add(i);
                positions.put(value, list);
            }
        }

        for(Integer key : positions.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Value: " + key);
            System.out.println("----------");
            for(Integer position : positions.get(key)) {
                System.out.println("Position: " + position);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
Value: 1
----------
Position: 0
Position: 6

Value: 2
----------
Position: 1
Position: 3
Position: 4
Position: 8

Value: 3
----------
Position: 2
Position: 5
Position: 7
```

Comment: its working..im sure i will be able to use this for my problem...that was a really good solution..

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.loknath.lab;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int input[] = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2 };
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (Integer integer : input) {
        set.add(integer);
    }

    for (Integer integer : set) {
        findIndexes(integer, input);
    }

}

public static void findIndexes(Integer integer, int[] input) {
    System.out.print("output_" + integer + "[]=   {");
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] == integer) {
            System.out.print(i + ",");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("}");
    System.out.println();
}

  }
```

output:_

```
 output_1[]=   {0,6,}
 output_2[]=   {1,3,4,8,} 
 output_3[]=   {2,5,7,}
```